# service logs output is frozen after huge log entry added

Tags: ibm-cloud, cloud-foundry

I have a Node.js service running on IBM Cloud. When I do logs output I can see it on logs page or through CF CLI:
cf logs

Once my service does huge data output into logs (i.e. 40-90K) data I cannot see any other logs then but service still alive and works fine. Is there a way to configure it on IBM Cloud itself or why it's freezing?

Comment: Did you try viewing the logs in Kibana instead? There's a button "View in Kibana" at the top of the logs page.

Comment: there is no such button :(